# Is Observable unsubscribed when I use first() pipe and i receive an error?

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs, pipe, observable, subscription

```
this.testSubscription = observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(
    data => {
        // do stuff here
    }, error => {
        // handle error here
    });
```

Consider the following Observable, in my case it's an Observable from the Apollo client library for GrapgQl. If i receive data normally, the Observable will be unsubscribed by the first() pipe.

I tried logging `this.testSubscription`, to see if the subscription is unsubscribed after making the call. But i don't know how to fake an error callback so i can't be sure if the subscription is unsubscribed when getting an error.

So does the first() pipe clean up the subscription when receiving an error? How can i test this?

Comment: Yes, `error` notification will make the chain unsubscribe. This is actually unrelated to `first()`, this is how RxJS works internally.

Answer (score 0):

`finalize` will when stream complete or error triggered. Also the third callback param in `subscribe` should also be called.

```
this.testSubscription = 
observable.pipe(first(),finalize(()=>console.log('done')).subscribe(null,null,()=>console.log('done'))
```